# Error installing Numpy via setup tools in virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, virtualenv, setuptools

I'm having trouble installing numpy in a virtualenv with setuptools. I'm using setup() with a list of dependencies passed in via install_requires. One of those dependencies is numpy. I get an error complaining that Python.h can't be found. Yet the python-dev package is installed. Running:

```
locate Python.h
```

returns

```
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

I can successfully install numpy if I use pip. But what I want is for numpy to be installed when I install my own python module via:

```
python setup.py install
```

Here's the error. Installing a Fortran compiler removes the Fortran errors, but still crashes with a missing Python.h file.

```
Searching for numpy==1.8.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
Best match: numpy 1.8.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.zip#md5=6c918bb91c0cfa055b16b13850cfcd6e
Processing numpy-1.8.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/setup.cfg
Running numpy-1.8.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/egg-dist-tmp-8m2hid
Running from numpy source directory.
Warning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage commandWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage fcompilernon-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
Warning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage distutilsWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage testingWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage f2pyWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension _dummyWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a library npysortWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension multiarrayWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension umathWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension scalarmath/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1522: UserWarning: 
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1531: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1534: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Warning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension _dotblasWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension umath_testsWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension test_rationalWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension struct_ufunc_testWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension multiarray_testsWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension operand_flag_testsWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage coreWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension _compiled_basenon-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'
Warning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage libWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage oldnumericWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension _capiWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage numarrayWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension fftpack_liteWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage fft/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1428: UserWarning: 
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1439: UserWarning: 
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1442: UserWarning: 
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Warning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension lapack_liteWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension _umath_linalgWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage linalgWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension mtrandWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage randomWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage maWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage matrixlibWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage compatWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage polynomialWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage docWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a subpackage numpyCould not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
Could not locate executable lf95
Could not locate executable pgfortran
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable fort
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable pathf95
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]
_configtest.o: In function `main':
/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
_configtest.o: In function `main':
/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]
_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 178, in <module>
    install_app()
  File "setup.py", line 119, in install_app
    entry_points=ENTRY_POINTS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 27, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 129, in install_for_development
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 687, in process_distribution
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 568, in resolve
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 806, in best_match
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 818, in obtain
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 609, in easy_install
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 639, in install_item
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 825, in install_eggs
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1031, in build_and_install
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1016, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 69, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 120, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 192, in <module>

  File "setup.py", line 185, in setup_package

  File "/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 177, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 10, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run
  File "/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 170, in build_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-lSyucn/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 427, in generate_config_h

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 288, in check_types

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

These are the versions I'm using:

```
Ubuntu: 12.10
Setuptools: 1.4.2
Numpy: 1.8.0
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: I have the python-dev package installed. Running `dpkg -s python-dev` confirms that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find what to do?

Comment: It is a known bug. I install it separately at the moment.

Comment: I am struggling with exactly the same issue. I even had installed using apt-get install python3-numpy but still it doesn't recognize numpy in python. I'll try to install it separately

Comment: RE: this is a bug; see: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2434

Comment: Work around is to manually install numpy in your (virtual) environment before running setup.py to install whatever you want to install that depends on numpy.

Comment: What does it mean to "install it separately", and how can I do it? I have no knowledge of Python, simply attempting to install a third-party program and ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a Fortran compiler installed. Try `apt-get install gfortran`.